# Как вытянуть из XML данные парсером (SAX)

Tags: xml, xmlparser, java, sax

Всем привет! Прошу помочь. Мне нужно на странице курсов валют([XML](http://bank-ua.com/export/currrate.xml)), вытянуть значения USD, EUR, RUB и записать их в соответствующие переменные.  Пока добился вот такой картины (отфильтровал всё лишнее):

> `Char3 : AUD
> Rate : 825.9537
> Char3 : AZM
> Rate : 1018.6058
> Char3 : GBP
> Rate : 1237.8745
> Char3 : BYR
> Rate : 0.0093
> Char3 : DKK
> Rate : 142.7915
> Char3 : USD
> Rate : 799.3000
> Char3 : EUR
> Rate : 1065.0673
> Char3 : ISK
> Rate : 6.1894
> Char3 : KZT
> Rate : 5.3127
> Char3 : CAD
> Rate : 797.2060
> Char3 : LVL
> Rate : 1522.3946
> Char3 : LTL
> Rate : 308.4648
> Char3 : MDL
> Rate : 66.2698
> Char3 : NOK
> Rate : 144.0351
> Char3 : PLN
> Rate : 254.1563
> Char3 : RUB
> Rate : 2.6543
> Char3 : SGD
> Rate : 646.0043
> Char3 : XDR
> Rate : 1220.1004
> Char3 : TRL
> Rate : 451.8358
> Char3 : TMM
> Rate : 280.4561
> Char3 : HUF
> Rate : 36.4275
> Char3 : UZS
> Rate : 0.3976
> Char3 : CZK
> Rate : 41.9549
> Char3 : SEK
> Rate : 125.9585
> Char3 : CHF
> Rate : 865.6972
> Char3 : CNY
> Rate : 128.2534
> Char3 : JPY
> Rate : 85.8717`

Вот мой код:

```
public class TestSaxParser {

public static void main(String argv[]) {

    try {

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

        DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

            boolean blchar = false;
            boolean bnrate = false;

            public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("char3")) {
                    blchar = true;
                }

                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("rate")) {
                    bnrate = true;
                }
            }

            public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
            String qName) throws SAXException {}

            public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

                if (blchar) {
                    System.out.println("Char3 : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                    blchar = false;
                }

                if (bnrate) {
                    System.out.println("Rate : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                    bnrate = false;
                }
            }
        };
        saxParser.parse("http://bank-ua.com/export/currrate.xml", handler);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Подскажите, как сохранить нужные мне значения))

Comment: Что сохранить, куда сохранить?

Comment: @Руслан Лозицкий может так?

       java TestSaxParser  > savefile.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вытянуть нужные значения можно доработав public void characters. Например что б вытянуть евро:

```
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
                  if (new String(ch, start, length).equalsIgnoreCase("EUR")){
                        FlName = true; 
                        FlChar = false; 
                        FlRate = false;

                   }

                   if (FlChar==true & FlName == true) {
                        String name = new String(ch, start, length);
                        System.out.print(name);
                        FlChar = false;

                   }
                   if (FlRate==true && FlName == true) {
                        String rate = new String(ch, start, length);
                        System.out.println(" - " + rate);
                        FlRate = false;
                        FlName = false;

                   }
        }
```